# Ajax Load in jquery when hit a link from the menu

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm new to Jquery and Ajax and have tried to solve a problem for over 1h now.

You can see the page here: http://smartcreations.se/test/test.html (If you click in the green area it have the effect I want it to have.)

Almost everything works as I want except i can't use the menu at the top to have the boxes to aminate and load the content as it does when you click on the green div.

So what I want from you guys is some input on how I can solve this, another point of view.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".box").click(function(){
$(this).animate({
top: '-50%'
}, 500, function() {
$(this).css('top', '150%');
$(this).appendTo('#container');             
$(".loadinghere").load($(this).attr('name'));
});
$(this).next().animate({
top: '50%'
}, 500);
});
});
```

This is the closest I get, but the links not works at all.

Comment: You want to load the content dynamically?

Comment: The pages is loading just fine, the problem is I can't link the navigation to the script without a few bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the problem. You mean, you don't know, how to tell the script, what page to load?

Comment: Have you checked the link? If you click on the big green box, it will works just fine. It will get the page that I want, but if you look at the top, I have a menu there, and if you click on "About me" then I want the effect you get if you click the big green box.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fake the click on the box by using e. g.

```
$("#box1").click();
```

but I would do it completely different:

```
<a href="107.html?nr=2" class="show">About me!</a>
<a href="108.html?nr=2" class="show">Portraits</a>
<a href="107.html?nr=2" class="show">Weddings</a>
<a href="109a.html?nr=2" class="show">Action</a>


<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).load(function(){
    $("a.show").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var click=$(this);
        var link=click.attr("href")+"#box";
        $("#box").after("<div id='box2' />").load(link, function(){
            $(this).animate({
                // your effect and stuff
            });
            // Rename the new box and throw out the old one
            // Make sure, it is not visible
            $("#box").remove();
            $("#box2").attr("id","box");
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

The idea is, to use full html and extract just the html out of `#box` and insert it on your current page. You can also use the newer history api or anchors for this. The main advantage is, that you can still use your page if JS is turned of. (Miss)using name or other html attributes for this is a really bad practice. If you need to, use the data attribute.

(The code is untested and the quick and dirty way just to give you an idea.)

Comment: Thank you Oliver. Tried this and what happend is that i got linked to the page. But will give it a try and try to understand were the problem is. :)

Comment: add `return false` at end of click handler to stop browser loading page

Comment: What ever I try with I get to a new page.

Comment: `preventDefault()` should prevent this!? Adding `return false` inside the the on handler will not hurt. I think IE has problems without it, but I don't know for sure. You will need to use full html pages with a div called box to work. I didn't mentioned it, so I do now. :-) jQuery will extract the html from this box. Maybe there is also an error in the code, than jQuery will fall back to normal behaviour. Check the javascript console for more info.

Comment: Still get the same result. How do you mean with full HTML pages? The loaded HTML page needs to have box element?

Comment: My suggestion is to use single pages with the content inside the box div. jQuery will extract it and insert it in the current page. As I can see you are using text files to insert the content, but this is not a good idea because if the loading fails or the user has javascript turned off your users will see nothing. My second suggestion will need a full rewrite of you pages. If you don't want this (for good reason) use the first one.

The whole issue is very complex for a jQuery beginner. I wonder if I gave you to much information at once. If so, my fault. :-)

Comment: Ah okej, thank you. Have tried with your first suggestion but got stuck there as well. Think I maybe have come closer to solve the problem now. But not sure, know the links loads into the boxes but I missing the amination.